# Watch OS keychain sharing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, keychain

Is it possible to access the shared keychain in WatchOS 4+?
I've set the exact same **Keychain Sharing > Keychain Group** of the iOS app (which syncs perfectly with a MacOS app), but all it finds is an empty object.

I'm using this library (https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) which works really well on `iOS` and `MacOS`, but not on `WatchOS`.

I shared the **Target Membership** of the classes involved to the Watch Extension (and I think it works, otherwise it would throw an error that was able to get the method or so), added the pod to watchOS like this

```
use_modular_headers!

def shared_pods
    pod 'KeychainAccess'
end

target 'Watch Extension' do
      platform :watchos, '4.0'
      shared_pods
end
```

My question is: am I missing some configurations? It looks like it is able to access the local keychain, but cannot sync with the shared one.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: Nope, still not working

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting to do the same thing, and it's a great pod to use to make the keychain easy to work with. However the part that needs to work is the iCloud Synchronizing for it move the data like you are thinking.

According to the [current Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW1), in the notes under the **Storing Data Securely in the Keychain**

> **NOTE**
>
> The kSecAttrSynchronizable key is **not** available in watchOS.

Without that, the WatchOS can not get the keychain data you have stored over on the iOS side. So you're doing the pods right, and it's a good pod, but WatchOS doesn't want us doing that.

TLDR; - You can't do it at this time.

Comment: right.  that was available in the very first watchOS version, but apple removed it.

Comment: Any chance this might have changed in watchOS6? The linked page has vanished, and there doesn't appear to be any equivalent statement.

Comment: I found something [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrsynchronizable). In short, sharing is possible for password, certificates and crypto keys.